# View parent folder using `ls -l ..$(which bash)`

Tags: bash

I Checked the bash I am working on

```
$ which bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
$ ls -l $(which bash)
lrwxr-xr-x 1 me 30 Oct 27 10:40 /usr/local/bin/bash -> ../Cellar/bash/4.4.23/bin/bash
```

Then I come to view bash's parent directory `usr/local/bin/`

```
$ ls -l ../$(which bash)
ls: cannot access '..//usr/local/bin/bash': No such file or directory
$ ls -l ..$(which bash)
ls: cannot access '../usr/local/bin/bash': No such file or directory
```

Unfortunately, I fall back to errors.

How could I navigate to bash's parent folder using command substitution $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is trying to run `ls` on `..//usr/local/bin/bash` which does not exits:

```
$ echo ../$(which bash)
..//usr/local/bin/bash
```

at the same time when you're using `ls -l ..$(which bash)`, the results depend on where your current working directory is, because you are addressing relatively.

So this one shouldn't give you any error (it looks for file not the parent DIR):

```
$ cd /usr
$ ls -ld ../$(which bash)
```

---

You have to use `dirname` command:

```
$ dirname $(which bash)
/bin
```

or:

```
$ ls -ld $(dirname $(which bash))
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 17 16:46 /bin
```

When your file is a link (Like bash in your case, and sh in my case):

```
$ ls -ld $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which sh)))
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 17 16:46 /bin
```

Comment: why this pattern fails, it seem reasonable from a view of a designer.

Comment: @avirate It's just the wrong way to do it... you are looking for a file which does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, using `which bash` won't always return the `bash` you are actually running, (you could be running another version, but with a path that include a different version). On Linux you can get the executable of the running shell from the `proc` file system using `/proc/$$/exe` (`$$` is the process id the or running shell) so what you want is

```
$(dirname $(readlink /proc/$$/exe))
```

Comment: The user is in this case running macOS.